# can't run executables ".x86" on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I've tried everything, installed a some libs and it doesn't work.
I'm trying to run this http://www.gameoftheyear420blazeit.com/

Comment: Do you get any errors you could add to your question to help figure out what the problem is? Run it via the terminal, simply by typing `./filename` and show the output of that to us.

Comment: bash: ./Home/Desktop/Linux/GAMEOFTHEYEAR420BLAZEIT.x86: No such file or directory

Comment: and I have 64 bits, I've installed some 32 libs

Comment: @Swagmaster: That error means the file doesn't exist. You have to use the right filename, and it is case sensitive. You can't write "Home" if it's called "home". Enter the first letters and press tab, the system will autocomplete the filename for you.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command to make the file executable:

```
chmod +x <path_to_file>/GAME\ OF\ THE\ YEAR\ 420BLAZEIT.x86
```

and *if* that does not work:

```
sudo chmod +x <path_to_file>/GAME\ OF\ THE\ YEAR\ 420BLAZEIT.x86
```

and run with this command:

```
<path_to_file>/GAME\ OF\ THE\ YEAR\ 420BLAZEIT.x86
```

or with this command:

```
cd <path_to_file>
./GAME\ OF\ THE\ YEAR\ 420BLAZEIT.x86
```

Comment: bash: /GAME OF THE YEAR 420BLAZEIT.x86: Permission denied

Comment: @Swagmaster I have updated my answer: `sudo chmod +x <path_to_file>/GAME\ OF\ THE\ YEAR\ 420BLAZEIT.x86`

Comment: still. bash: /GAME OF THE YEAR 420BLAZEIT.x86: Permission denied

Comment: run this command: `nano`

Answer (score -1):

Did you read that webpage all the way to the bottom?  I quote:

> This game is a parody and work of fiction.

No, seriously.  I would seriously doubt if anything you downloaded will run in any way.  I suggest you try playing games available in the Ubuntu Software Center.  Those games are certified to work with ubuntu and are safe to play.

Comment: So, you are saying that a parody game won't run at all?

Comment: I'm saying that one should never be too disappointed when trying to run software which is in any way claiming to be a joke.  Take that any way you wish.  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: but I can't run any linux executable, and it is allowed in properties

Comment: That seems unlikely.  Have you tried sudo as well?

Comment: waah, sudo for a unknown game? Bad idea.

Comment: you guys are going to make me afraid to make intelligent comments.  First A.B.  I did not suggest sudo for the game.  I was referring to the OP's comment that he could not run ANY LINUX EXECUTABLE.  So you see, I was referring to performing tests of reputable executables using sudo.